# What to do with "Code -36" questions

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Today I stumbled upon [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212792/81404). Code -36 is a file permissions error on OS X, and resolution is really dependent on what type of file is attempting to be opened.

If it's an app, there's a [Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/898124/the-application-someapp-app-can-t-be-opened), there's a command-line utility for [dot file conflicts](http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/21/fix-error-code-36-finder-mac-os-x/), and even an entire [CNET](http://www.cnet.com/news/tutorial-what-to-do-when-a-mac-os-x-application-will-not-launch/) article on the subject.

Should one master question be asked an answered, should the questions be addresses when asked, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer listing everything you've found and the circumstances the findings apply seems to be a good way to proceed in this case (and definitively better than a lot of back and forth in the comments to nail down the cause).